# Advance serialization in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to achieve something with Django Rest Framework.
The idea is for a model to have several fields of several types in read-only, and have the same fields writable for the user that would take precedence when serving the data.
Since this should not be very clear, an example :

The model would be :

```
class Site(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'),max_length=300)
    title_modified = models.CharField(_('Title'),max_length=300)
```

The viewset to be defined :

```
class SiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = SiteSerializer
   queryset = Site.objects.all()
```

The serializer :

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        depth = 1
```

What i want to do is be able to only serve the "title" data to the client, but the title would have either the title field if title_modified is empty or the title_modified field if it's not empty.
On the same idea when the client writes to the title i would like my server to write the data to title_modified instead and always leave the title info untouched.

I don't know how to achieve this a way that's generic enough to be applicable to all types of fields.
I thought it would simply require some magic on the serialization/unserialization but i can't seem to find it.

Any idea would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can override the to_representation() method of serializer to solve your problem:

```
class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Site
       depth = 1
       exclude = ('title')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(SiteSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        if not rep.get('title_modified', ''):
            rep['title_modified'] = instance.title
        return rep
```

This will return title as title_modified if title_modified is empty. User will always work on title_modified as required.
For more details please read [modelserializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) and [Advanced serializer usage](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#advanced-serializer-usage).

Comment: Great thanks! This is exactly what i wanted. Well it's even simpler than what i had in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using ModelViewSets, you can override the default actions like .list(), .retrieve(), .create(), etc to do what you want or create your custom actions. Relevant info for ModelViewSets can be found [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) and [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).

Actually, there are plenty of ways to go about this, and you do not even need to use ModelViewSet. You can actually use the generic views for this one. The real trick is to leverage the power of the CBVs and OOP in general. Here is a sample code wherein you provide a custom retrieval process of a single instance, while retaining all the rest's out-of-the-box behavior that a ModelViewSet provides.

```
class SiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer
    queryset = Site.objects.all()

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        # You can use the serializer_class specified above (SiteSerializer)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)

        # Or perform some other manipulation on your instance first,
        # then use a totally different serializer for your needs
        instance = data_manipulation(instance)
        serializer = AnotherSiteSerializer(instance)

        # Finally return serialized data
        return Response(serializer.data)

        # Or if you want, return random gibberish.
        return Response({'hello': 'world'})
```